# select node based on the text of the next level node

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have this xml:

```
<Checklist>
<ChecklistGroup id="" val="1" seq="" ilid="">
    <name>Group1</name>
    <ChecklistItem id="" val="1" seq="1" pcid="" piid="">
        <name>sb1</name>
    </ChecklistItem>
    <ChecklistItem id="" val="1" seq="2" pcid="" piid="">
        <name>sb2</name>
    </ChecklistItem>
    <ChecklistItem id="" val="1" seq="3" pcid="" piid="">
        <name>sb3</name>
    </ChecklistItem>
</ChecklistGroup>
</Checklist>
```

There can be a lot of ChecklistGroup nodes. How do I select the **ChecklistGroup** node based on the text of the next node which is '**name**'. I want to select the checklistgroup node where it has a name of '**Group1**'

How do i do that in javascript/jquery?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like below where `$xml` is the jQuery object reference to the xml

```
var $grp = $xml.find('ChecklistGroup > name').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Group1'
}).parent()
```

Note: [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) was not used since it can return partial matches